# Prove $f=\cos(\vartheta)$ and $g=\sin(\vartheta)$ based on given assumptions

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable real functions on an interval $I$. Suppose that $f^2+g^2=1$ and that $f(0)=\cos\vartheta_0$ and $g(0)=\sin\vartheta_0$, where $\vartheta_0 \in \Bbb R$.

If $\vartheta$ is a function such that: $$\vartheta=\vartheta_0+\int_0^t (fg'-f'g)du$$ 
Prove that $$f=\cos\vartheta$$ $$g=\sin\vartheta$$

Hint: We want $(f-\cos\vartheta)^2+(g-\sin\vartheta)^2=0$, so show that its derivative is zero.

---

My progress only goes so far as to notice that $fg'-f'g=f^2\frac{d}{du}(\frac{g}{f})$, with which I cannot seem to do anything.

I don't even understand what it is that I'm trying to show the derivative of which is zero, as the hint points out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that the functions $f,g$ are ${\mathcal C}^1$. Then the function $\theta(t)$ given in the hint exists and is differentiable.

a) Note that the formula given for $\theta$ is 
$$\theta(t)=\theta_0+\int_0^t (f^{\prime}(u)g(u)-g^ {\prime}(u)f(u))du$$
As $f^{\prime}(u)g(u)-g^ {\prime}(u)f(u)$ is continuous, we have $$\theta^{\prime}(t)=f^{\prime}(t)g(t)-g^ {\prime}(t)f(t) $$

and $\theta(0)=\theta_0$.

b) Let $h(t)=(f(t)-\cos(\theta(t))^2+(g(t)-\sin(\theta(t))^2$. Then $h(0)=0$. Hence if $h^ {\prime}(t)=0$, we have $h(t)=$ constant $=0$, and we are done, as this imply $f(t)=\cos(\theta(t))$ and $g(t)=\sin(\theta(t))$ for all $t$.

c) Compute now the derivative of $h(t)$ :
$$h^{\prime}(t)=2(f^{\prime}(t)+\theta^{\prime}(t)\sin(\theta(t))(f(t)-\cos(\theta(t))+2(g^{\prime}(t)-\theta^{\prime}(t)\cos(\theta(t))(g(t)-\sin(\theta(t))$$

Hence
$$h^{\prime}(t)=2(f^{\prime}(t)f(t)+g^{\prime}(t)g(t)+\sin(\theta(t))(f^{2}g^{\prime}(t)-f(t)f^{\prime}(t)-g^{\prime}(t))+\cos(\theta(t))(g^2(t)f^{\prime}(t)-f(t)g^{\prime}(t)g(t)-f^{\prime}(t)))$$

Now use the fact that the derivative $2(f^{\prime}f+g^{\prime}g)$ of $f^2+g^2$ is zero, and for the coefficients of $\sin(\theta(t))$ and of $\cos(\theta(t))$, use $f^2=1-g^2$, $g^2=1-f^2$ to finish.

Comment: It would be a bit easier if we simplified $h(t)$ first as $h(t)=2-2[f\cos\theta+g\sin\theta]$.

Comment: @A.G Yes, your remark simplify a lot the computations, thank you.

Comment: It makes sense to me, but is it actually rigorous to just say that $\theta'(t)=f'(t)g(t)-g'(t)f(t)$ based on the given equation?

Comment: @Jon Snow. Your remark is good: I have supposed that the functions $f$ and $g$ are ${\mathcal C}^1$. Then the function $f^{\prime}(t)g(t)-g^{\prime}(t)f(t)$ is integrable and then $\theta(t)$ exist, is differentiable and $\theta^{\prime}(t)=f^{\prime}(t)g(t)-g^{\prime}(t)f(t)$. But the hypothesis suggest that this is the case. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h=(f-\cos\theta)^2+(g-\sin\theta)^2$.

Note that $ff^\prime+gg^\prime=0$ (only differentiate $f^2+g^2=1$), and $\theta^\prime=fg^\prime-f^\prime g$. Thus:

$\begin{eqnarray}
h^\prime&=&2(f-\cos\theta)(f^\prime+\theta^\prime\sin\theta)+2(g-\sin\theta)(g^\prime-\theta^\prime\cos\theta)\\
&=&\,2ff^\prime+2f\theta^\prime\sin\theta-2f^\prime\cos\theta-2\theta^\prime\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
&&2gg^\prime-2g\theta^\prime\cos\theta-2g^\prime\sin\theta+2\theta^\prime\sin\theta\cos\theta\\
&=&2f\theta^\prime\sin\theta-2f^\prime\cos\theta-2g\theta^\prime\cos\theta-2g^\prime\sin\theta\\
&=&2\theta^\prime(f\sin\theta-g\cos\theta)-2(f^\prime\cos\theta+g\prime\sin\theta)\\
&=&2(fg^\prime-f^\prime g)(f\sin\theta-g\cos\theta)-2(f^\prime\cos\theta+g\prime\sin\theta)\\
&=&2f^2g^\prime\sin\theta-2fgg^\prime\cos\theta-2ff^\prime  g\sin\theta+2f^\prime g^2\cos\theta-2g^\prime\sin\theta-2f^\prime\cos\theta\\
&=&2g^\prime\sin\theta(f^2-1)+f^\prime\cos\theta(g^2-1)-2fgg^\prime\cos\theta-2ff^\prime  g\sin\theta\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}$

Thus $h$ is constant. But $h(0)=0$ (by hypothesis). Then $h=0$.

Moreover, $h=0$ implies $f-\cos\theta=0$ and $g-\sin\theta=0$ and done.